# On button tapping how to go back to previous iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

On tapping push notification my app launched, now I want go back on previous app on tapping button from my app. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. Apple does not give you the ability to switch apps.